# How to read image from file directory in Jupyter Notebook using OpenCV?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to read an image from the laptop in Jupyter notebook using `imread()` of OpenCV. When I execute the program by specifying the address of the file, it shows the following error:

```
img2 = cv.imread('D:\Photos\roaches.jpg')
cv.imshow("Cockroaches", img2)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-645759bb8eb6> in <module>
      1 img2 = cv.imread('D:\Photos\roaches.jpg')
----> 2 cv.imshow("Cockroaches", img2)
      3 cv.waitKey(0)
      4 cv.destroyAllWindows()

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

[Screenshot of the notebook snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGif0.png)

However, when I placed the image in the directory where Jupyter notebook is running, the code worked fine.
How can I read any image from the computer without placing it in the Jupyter notebook directory?